# Node.Js add record using sequelize/body parser and mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Given the following code, how can I use body-parser & sequelize to add a student to the database? The response body should be {"message": "created"}.
Tried to following way but it's not working

The code: https://pastebin.com/raw/BCdpQLWJ

```
student.create({
  name: req.body.name,
  address: req.body.address,
  age: req.body.age
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to declare the model mapping:

```
const { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
class Student extends Model {}
const sequelize = new Sequelize(<connection parameters go here>)
Student.init({
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
  adddress: DataTypes.STRING,
  age: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, { sequelize, modelName: 'student' });
```

Then you have to call create function:

```
Student.create({
name: req.body.name,
address: req.body.address,
age: req.body.age}).then(result=> {console.log({"message": "created"})});
```

If you want to store multiple records:

```
await sequelize.sync({force : true})
const bulk = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      bulk.push({
         name : 'name ' + i,
         address : 'some address on ' + i + 'th street',
         age : 30 + i
     });
     await Student.bulkCreate(bulk);
 }
 res.status(201).json({message : 'created'})
```